# Facebook user access token vs application access token vs page access token

Tags: android, ios, facebook, oauth, web

I have read the document *[Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)* (official from Facebook). I still don't understand the difference between these three types of access token Facebook provided.
There are some examples given on the site, but I still don't quite get it.

Is there a plain example of each and why one would be used over the other?

Put particular emphasis on the application access token, that is where I get confused.

Comment: Just read about `user`, `page` and `application` objects in documentation, fields and connections have description about which one is needed to access that data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They basically work as you would expect.

User access token: Act as a user to access their information, post as them, etc.

[App access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/): Change settings for an app, get app stats, etc.

[Page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/): Same as a user access token but for pages.

Comment: Does a page access token expire? If so what is it's default expiration time when requesting through the PHP SDK and how would one go about prolonging it.